# Ios: load custom view in xib

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I've designed my custom view in xib. I have `CustomView.h/m` + `CustomView.xib`. In xib file I set view class to CustomView.

Now I want to use this view in other xib. I've created another xib, added view and set it class to `CustomView`, but it's not loaded.

How to load my CustomView correctly?

Comment: Read this it will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095359/using-xib-object-inside-another-xib

Comment: @Omarj provided answer provides infinite loop, you cannot call loadNib in initWithCode method

Comment: More precisely, how are you loading `CustomView` and what is exactly happening? Are you pushing a new `UIViewController`?

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare currently, I've just added in other xib view and set its class to `CustomView`. Nothing happens, customview isn't loaded. I guess I need to write some code to make it appear in UI

Comment: If so, present question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405916/correct-way-to-load-a-nib-for-a-uiview-subclass

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare in that question view is loaded from code, not from xib/storyboard

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

> You can use `CustomView.h/m` in as many `.XIB` files as you see fit, including `.storyboard`

The problem lies in *how* you load the second view.

```
    if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("id") as? UIViewController {
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

See:

- [Correct way to load a Nib for a UIView subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405916/correct-way-to-load-a-nib-for-a-uiview-subclass)
- [load view form StoryBoard that does not have a Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666168/load-view-form-storyboard-that-does-not-have-a-segue).

Comment: that I was asking: HOW to load it:)

Comment: in that question view is loaded from code, not from xib/storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `IB_Designable` keyword to make your custom view look properly in IB. But designing the custom view in a nib and not overriding drawRect makes it more involved. Check out [this link](http://justabeech.com/2014/07/27/xcode-6-live-rendering-from-nib/) to see how you can do it: